# Set mouse cursor image with C/C++ in macOS

Tags: c++, c, macos

Is it possible to change the mouse cursor image in macOS from a C/C++ program? Or does it have to be done from a full-on Objective-C/Swift app? Is there a way to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor) in C/C++?

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa only sets the calling application's cursor. An application's cursor is only used when that application is the current active application. If a different app is active, then that app's cursor is shown.

So, you do need a "full-on … app" to affect the cursor. If you were hoping to do this from a command-line program, that won't work.

However, you don't necessarily need to code an app in Objective-C or Swift. You could use a C++ framework like Qt or WxWidgets. (Those will use Objective-C or Swift under the hood because it's not really feasible to avoid that.)

Comment: Would the “app’s cursor” still be the one shown even if the cursor leaves its window (so long as it’s app is still the active/focused one)?

Comment: Mostly, but not absolutely. For example, when you mouse over the Dock, the cursor is always reset to the standard arrow (or, if you're over its divider, a double-headed arrow resize cursor).